# Consider Adding Static Interface Methods to Provide a Single Entry Point for Object Creation

Tags: java, oop, java-8, instantiation, factory-pattern

Does "implementation" [below](https://dzone.com/articles/the-java-8-api-design-principles) mean instance of an object?  Perhaps they mean the implementing code.

> Consider adding static interface methods, to allow the client code to
>   create (potentially specialized) objects that implement the interface.
>   For example, if we have an interface Point with two methods int x()
>   and int y(), then we can expose a static method Point.of(int x, int y)
>   that produces a (hidden) implementation of the interface.
>
> So, if x and y are both zero, we can return a special implementation
>   class PointOrigoImpl (with no x or y fields), or else we return
>   another class PointImpl that holds the given x and y values. Ensure
>   that the implementation classes are in another package that are
>   clearly not a part of the API (e.g. put the Point interface in
>   com.company. product.shape and the implementations in
>   com.company.product.internal.shape).
>
> Do This:
>
> `Point point = Point.of(1,2);`
>
> Don't Do This:
>
> `Point point = new PointImpl(1,2);`

The advantage being that this enforces encapsulation?  However, if the implementation is package private and not part of the API, would that not create access problems?  If the client, "world" as here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

doesn't have access to the implementation of `Point` then how can it possibly instantiate a new `Point` as above for "do this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, if we have an interface Point with two methods int x()
>   and int y(), then we can expose a static method Point.of(int x, int y)
>   that produces a (hidden) implementation of the interface.

1) Be aware, since Java 8 you can add a static method in an interface, but before you cannot.

2) I have some difficulties to understand this advise :

> So, if x and y are both zero, we can return a special implementation
>   class PointOrigoImpl (with no x or y fields), or else we return
>   another class PointImpl that holds the given x and y values. Ensure
>   that the implementation classes are in another package that are
>   clearly not a part of the API (e.g. put the Point interface in
>   com.company. product.shape and the implementations in
>   com.company.product.internal.shape).

Here is an example `Point` class that matches to the text you refer to:

```
package com.company.product.shape;

import com.company.product.internal.shape.PointOrigoImpl;
import com.company.product.internal.shape.PointImpl;

public interface Point{
   int x();
   int y();     
   static Point of(int x, int y) {
      if (x == 0 && y == 0){
         return new PointOrigoImpl();
      }
      return new PointImpl(x, y);
  }
}
```

If the `Point` interface is provided to clients and that it declares the factory method, to compile fine, the `Point`interface has to necessarily have the  visibility to `PointOrigoImpl` and `PointImpl` classes in order to instantiate them.

As the `Point` interface and the subclasses are in two distinct packages (`com.company.product.shape` and `com.company.product.internal.shape`),
that means that `PointImpl` and `PointOrigoImpl` should have a public constructor otherwise `Point` could not instantiate them.
Finally, clients who manipulate Points may also instantiate the constructor of `PointImpl` and `PointOrigoImpl` subclasses.

It defeats the purpose of a factory that doesn't want to expose the implementation to choose itself the implementation to return.

An interface is public and is designed to be fully accessible to the client.
So as a general rule it should not contain implementations that we don't want to expose to clients.

3) Here :

> The advantage being that this enforces encapsulation? However, if the
>   implementation is package private and not part of the API, would that
>   not create access problems? If the client, "world" as here:
>   doesn't have access to the implementation of Point then how can it
>   possibly instantiate a new Point as above for "do this"?

I suppose you wonder why the text says :
 **Ensure that the implementation classes are in another package that are clearly not a part of the API**.

In the text you refer to, the author wants to let the interface be known by `Point` clients but he doesn't want to subclasses of `Point` be known because he wants to decide the Point subclass to return according to the parameter used in the factory Point.

Point clients will know only this interface.

In Java, in order to not providing the access to implementation classes you can use public class, interface and inner private class :

- the public class is exposed to clients to call the factory method that returns the implementation
- the interface class is known by all and has no coupling with the implementation.
- The inner private class makes part of the public class. The client cannot sees it but the factory see it to return the suitable implementation.

With the example you refer to, it would be straight.

Point (interface) :

```
public interface Point{
   int x();
   int y();            
}
```

Point factory (public class that contains private classes) :

```
public final class PointFactory {

    // private classes
    private class PointImpl implements Point {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        private PointImpl(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int x() {
            return x;
        }

        public int y() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    private class PointOrigoImpl implements Point {

        public int x() {
            return 0;
        }

        public int y() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // end private classes

    public Point of(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            return new PointOrigoImpl();
        }
        return new PointImpl(x, y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `PointImpl` would also have exposed API to create itself, maybe in form of `PointImpl.create(int x, int y)` and  `PointOrigoImpl.create()`. Since they are both in the internal package, they can be public and `Point.of` can use them freely, while technically "hidden" from the user of the API because they residue in `com.company.product.internal.shape`.

Of course, this operates on good faith that programmer will not abuse `PointImpl.create` instead of `Point.of`, but that is normal. If programmer wants to break encapsulation (or needs so), there is no stopping him anyways (as it should be).

Answer (score 0):

> If the client, "world" doesn't have access to the implementation of Point then how can it possibly instantiate a new Point as above for "do this"?

The client does not need to instantiate as the instantiation happens in the `Point` itself. And as the implementation `implements` the interface `Point`, all publicly accessible methods of `Point` should be accessible to the client and client is always free to play with the methods.